When current is passed through a wire, does it heat up uniformly, or is there a temperature differential?
When a current is passed through a wire (or a very long resistor), does the wire heat up uniformly? Or does it get hottest at one end and then get hotter down its length, following the flow of the current? I know that the resistance will cause electricity to get dissipated as heat, but I can't quite figure out if this dissipation means that the far end of the wire will have less current flowing through it to start, such that it dissipates less heat to start.

How does the wire in a fuse fail under excess current? do the ends fail? or the middle? Are the conditions for heat transfer the same at all points?

@SolarMike - fuses, in my experience, tend to fail in the middle, but I assume that was from heat dissipation with contact at the ends, not necessarily because of anything to do with how it intrinsically heats up.

OP - think about the physical mechanism of current flow, which is mostly electrons jumping from atom to atom, and heat, which is the energy released by them doing so.

If the wire has negligible resistance, then I would expect any difference to be negligible, as there is negligible voltage drop across the wire (and this would essentially happen at the speed of light). But if R is really large, then there should either be a voltage drop or a decrease in current across the wire. But I can't figure out if this means there's a differential in power loss, or if this is constant.

If the wire is uniform in cross-section and composition and temperature (and hence resistance per linear unit), for a given current, the heat produced per linear unit (mm or inch) will be constant.
Whether that results in uniform temperature depends on the heat loss at any given point along the wire. Heat loss is by conduction, convection and radiation. Convection is complex, but folks such as King† (1914) have come up with mathematical models.
There is an often important secondary effect in that the resistance of the wire will change with temperature. Generally it will increase with temperature, more-or-less proportionally to (absolute) temperature for elemental metals, and it can be much less for some alloys such as Constantan or other resistance wire alloys. In the case of large temperature changes that can lead to or exacerbate hot spots such as the centre of a fuse element. The ends lose heat due to terminations, so the center gets hotter and hotter and will stabilize at a much higher temperature than the ends or it will melt and the fuse opens.

† 1. L. V. King, On the Convection of Heat from Small Cylinders In a Stream of Fluid: Determination of the Convection Constants of Small
Platinum Wires with Application to Hot-Wire Anemometry, Phil. Trans.
Roy. Soc., A214, 373-432,
1914.



I can't quite figure out if this dissipation means that the far end of
the wire will have less current flowing through it

If current enters a wire (or long resistor) it leaves the wire having the same magnitude hence, power and heat is generated throughout the wire. There are some exceptions when the driving voltage is very high frequency because there tends to be capacitive currents to ground that make the "in" current a bit more than the "out" current.
There are also transmission line effects that can produce anomalies but generally, at DC or low frequencies: -
It's safe to assume the current entering a resistor/wire is the same magnitude as the current leaving that resistor/wire.

does the wire heat up uniformly?

It may not heat up uniformly if the terminations of the wire/resistor act like heat sinks due to their increased surface area. This will tend to make the mid portion of the wire heat up to a higher temperature.

Or does it get hottest at one end and then get hotter down its length,
following the flow of the current?

It's hard to envisage a situation where that would happen. I mean, you could make a resistance wire such that it has more air-flow across it at the infeed end and that could look like that scenario.

To be probably excessively pedantic, at high enough voltages, current can also leave the wire before reaching the other end via dielectric breakdown.

@Hearth very true.

But for a large enough resistance, isn't there a voltage drop across the wire? (for a constant current) Would this not manifest as a temperature drop as well?

@user3037237 there will be a volt drop across any resistance wire proportional to current and this has no effect on how the heat is distributed.

Ok that's about as straightforward a response as I can hope for. Thanks!
